# IPTables - allow communication between two hosts , drop everything else

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, firewall

I have a router, which I want to configure to block all outgoing traffic to the Internet. As far as I understand, I need to drop forwarded packets. In addition I want to allow traffic between one machine and several other machines in the internal LAN.

To do tried the following:

```
IPT="/sbin/iptables"

LOCAL_CONTROLLER="192.168.1.2"
SUBNET="192.168.1."
MACHINE_IPS="100 101 102 103 104"

for MACHINE in ${MACHINE_IPS}; do
    $IPT -A FORWARD -s $LOCAL_CONTROLLER -j ACCEPT
    $IPT -A FORWARD -s $SUBNET$MACHINE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    $IPT -A FORWARD -s $SUBNET$MACHINE -d $LOCAL_CONTROLLER -j ACCEPT 
    $IPT -A FORWARD -s $SUBNET$MACHINE -j DROP
done
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as I expected, and traffic from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.103 and back is blocked.

Can you point out where my script is wrong?

Comment: Does your router forward between 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.103? what does your network structure look like?

Comment: All the hosts in my network are listed already. If I don't run the script there is communication between the hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FORWARD` queue is only used when the server is question *is the router*, for dealing with incoming/outgoing packets outside of your network; it is used for blocking/accepting the  routing of packets outside your network (at router level).

For controlling connections at host level, you normally use `INPUT`or `OUTPUT` queues, no matter where the connections are coming from, as they do not do routing (e.g. do not do IP Forwarding).

If you really want a group of machines in a local network to talk among themselves, and not talk with the Internet, the simplest approach of all is not defining a gateway on that machines.

If you still with to do with `iptables` you have to use the `INPUT` queue in your script in lieu of `FORWARD`.

If your main worry is traffic going to the Internet, whilst I do prefer not giving them a gateway to go out, you have to use the `OUTPUT` queue in the local machines.

As in:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

(192.168.1.0/24 -> all the machines in the 192.168.1 network)

Be aware that if you coming via ssh from another network, you will effectively lock yourself out with these rules.

However, if your router is a linux box, it maybe enough to write as a FORWARD rule to lock a couple of machines from the Internet:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.11 -J DROP
```

From `man iptables`:

> INPUT (for packets destined to local sockets)
>   FORWARD (for packets being routed through the box)
>   OUTPUT (for locally-generated packets).

Comment: The thing is, I don't have any control on those machines. I must give them IP address, because I need to communicate with services running on them, but I don't want to allow traffic from these machines to the Internet. Is this possible?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So the FORWARD is used for incoming traffic from the internet to the machines in my network?

Comment: I refer to my first paragraph. If you router is a linux box like mine, than you have to deal with the FORWARD queue for incoming/outgoing packets outside of your network. Non-router machines only know the INPUT and OUTPUT queue.

Comment: my router is a Linux box. The thing is, there is no rule dropping packets which are forwarded (accept to what I added).

Comment: Added to the answer.